# Google now card not triggering

Tags: google-schemas

The schema which I followed on Google developers site, does not help me trigger a Google now card, I am passing JSON inside the HTML tag and sending an Event-Registration email but nothing happens. Please provide help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just copy and paste the JSON example that's on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/event-reservation), you'll see that the startDate is in 2017:

```
"startDate": "2017-03-06T19:30:00-08:00"
```

Try inputting an earlier startDate, like today for example:

```
"startDate": "2015-06-04T10:30:00-08:00"
```

Otherwise, you won't see your card until March 6th 2017. If this is not the case, could you post your markup.

Comment: I changed date and still nothing happens... Link to my code https://docs.google.com/document/d/1jVDmM0lQW8uczA-VVtf9iE_cUpgL5T6uohIAOvWAkRE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I see a few things. You're inputting ("reservationStatus": "confirmed") when it should be ("reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/Confirmed"). Try this example (https://goo.gl/oM5DSB). Let me know if the markup works for you. You should get a card like this (http://i.stack.imgur.com/2xHPr.jpg).

Comment: Thank you so much Sir, it works for me.... now one last doubt, how to add seat number and ticket number to be shown on the card. This is the last thing that I need then my work is done.....

Comment: @Kavittechie my pleasure. If you would be so kind to set my response as the "Answer", it would be even nicer ;) thanks playa.

Comment: the showing up of google card is very abrupt... like on friday when I was testing it.. the google now card showed instantly but now when I test it, it shows 20 mins after receiving email. What could be the reason behind it... Any particular reason...

Comment: @Kavittechie I've noticed this as well. I'm not sure if it has to do with time we're inputting for the startData property or if it's our account syncing the data. I'll have to research this one more.

Comment: thanks for an early reply ... do let me know if you find the correct reason behind till then I will also try to research on it...  One more thing I wanted to ask which schema will I use if I want to generate a card for a payment email done by a person. Like payment of this much amount has been made. Thank you...

Comment: @Kavittechie The schema that would best fit a payment transaction is the Order schema. This will not trigger a Now card. However, if you're sending a package, the ParcelDelivery schema will generate a Now card. You can find the supported Now schemas here: https://developers.google.com/schemas/now/cards

Comment: I was researching help for google now on net I found a person posting this -> "I've finally got this to work. For some reason the starter tutorial they provide doesn't give you adequate markup to generate a google now card. Instead, you should use the event without reservation markup". What does this exactly means, I think this could also help us generating Google now cards at proper time...

Comment: @Kavittechie The thing with using a top level "Event" instead of "EventReservation" is you're not able to use "url" or "modifyReservationUrl", etc. I guess it depends on what you need to achieve. The documentation on Event with RSVP can be found here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/rsvp-action

Comment: one advantage of using Google schemas is that google calendar parses it very nicely and also provides you notification of the Event...

Comment: have you worked on schemas that get parsed by passbook in iPhones ... l

Comment: @Kavittechie no I haven't.

Comment: I have noticed a pattern, I don't know whether it's correct inference or not but whenever I send my schema email to myself using my office wifi, it generates a card after 1 or 2 hours but when I use my home wifi, it generates the card within 5 mins, so I am assuming that the reason could be my office wifi is slow, so it takes time for google now to synchronize.

Comment: @Kavittechie Thanks, I'll have to look into that.

Comment: I have one more question, the Event Card generation works fine when I send email to myself using Google email tester, so I thought of embedding it in real time email generator, so when anyone books an event ticket the e-ticket is send to the customer with my <script> code in it, but that is neither generating a card nor showing the date on google calender, so I am assuming that code is not getting parsed. Please provide your suggestions.

Comment: @Kavittechie for new questions, you should create a new post. Event Reservation won't show for your customers because you will have to be "whitelisted" for Gmail Schemas. Go to the registration page (https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google) and submit a form.

Comment: Thanks, ya from next time I will create a new post for every question.